# How to check if GPS is enabled or not?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, gps, ionic-framework

I want to check if GPS is enabled or not in my corodva angular application, if it is disabled then popup notification will appear to provide option to  enable it. Similar to the functionality of the native apps.

Can someone give me an example on how to get this working?

Comment: Have you already tried with [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)?

Comment: yes i added plugin of  cordova-plugin-geolocation

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin,

cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic

Which has method like below to check device gps setting,

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
    console.log("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));},
    function(error){ 
       console.error("The following error occurred:"+error);
    });
```

For More details, [click here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)

Comment: when i excut this command (cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic) i found this error :Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Error: Uh oh!
Invalid Version: undefined

Comment: Have you also tried with `cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin` ?

Comment: always this error ,@beaver i use ionic framwork in cordova

Comment: !JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.plugins.diagnostic')

Comment: what is your system info ? (you can get this by 'ionic info' command)

Comment: I get the following error:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740031/error-ts2339-property-diagnostic-does-not-exist-on-type-cordovaplugins